# Make mandatory to put merge request link in "Ready to merge" column

Tags: jira, jira-agile

In my job we are creating a Jira board to manage our tickets. I created a column called "Ready to merge", and I want that when a ticket is passed from "In progress" to "Ready to merge" to be mandatory to put the link of the merge request.

Do you know if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set a condition on the transition to "Ready to merge"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/advanced-workflow-configuration-776636620.html).

It looks like "Value Field" will do the job. This is the description for it:

> Allows to execute a transition if the given value of a field is equal to a constant value, or simply set.

[Alternatively, you could also add a Field Required validator.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-make-jira-applications-fields-required-in-a-workflow-transition-691011903.html)